# NetworkInfo has been deprecated by API 29

Tags: android, kotlin, deprecated, networkinfo

I wanted to check the network connection. So, I used `ConnectivityManager.activateNetworkInfo.isConnected`

unfortunately, that's deprecated in API 29.

```
private fun isOnline(): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager = appContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    val networkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected
}
```

and you can see depreciation message here

[image]

Comment: @AhmadSabeh , MayRestinPeace: the problem is not TYPE...

Comment: @Quicklearner , Thanks but already solved.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

It's deprecated base on [Google Document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo)

- getActiveNetworkInfo is deprecated on API 29.
- getAllNetworkInfo is deprecated on API 23.

So, If you want to find the Network Connection status, you can use this code.

kotlin :

```
 private fun isNetworkAvailable(context: Context): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        val nw      = connectivityManager.activeNetwork ?: return false
        val actNw = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(nw) ?: return false
        return when {
            actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
            actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
            //for other device how are able to connect with Ethernet
            actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> true
            //for check internet over Bluetooth
            actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_BLUETOOTH) -> true
            else -> false
        }
    } else {
        return connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo?.isConnected ?: false
    }
}
```

Java :

```
private Boolean isNetworkAvailable(Application application) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) application.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        Network nw = connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork();
        if (nw == null) return false;
        NetworkCapabilities actNw = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(nw);
        return actNw != null && (actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) || actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) || actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) || actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_BLUETOOTH));
    } else {
        NetworkInfo nwInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return nwInfo != null && nwInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

you can see all [NetworkCapability](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities) here.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: works great, thank you. one comment on the Kotlin version, you can cast the connectivity manager as nullable `ConnectivityManager?` and check for `null` to avoid NPE

Comment: Hello, nwInfo.isConnected(); is still deprecated in Api 29